# change date format using locale

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am working on a simple textbox that has Dojo datepicker. The code below parses the date correctly with locale `en-gb` `(dd/mm/yyyy)`. However the date that is picked from the datepicker is still in locale `en-us` `(mm/dd/yyyy)`. So, it cannot parse the date that if it exceeds the 12th of the month.

```
        require(["dojo/date/locale","dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],function(locale,Button,dom){
            var myButton = new Button({
                label: "Submit Date",
                onClick: function(){
                    var date = locale.parse(dom.byId("date1").value,{
                        formatLength:'short',
                        selector:'date', 
                        locale:'en-gb'
                    });
                    alert(date);
                }
            }, "submit");
        });
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the value of "dom.byId('date1').value" when your onClick is invoked?  Perhaps you could create a jsFiddle that you could post as a link that would allow us to examine the story in place?

Comment: I wasnt able to create a fiddle. Here is the complete code: http://dabblet.com/gist/7868328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by mentioning the date format explicitly.

```
onClick: function(){
    var date = locale.parse(dom.byId("date1").value,{
        formatLength:'short',
        selector:'date', 
        locale:'en-gb',
        datePattern:'dd/MM/yyyy'
    });
    alert(date.toLocaleString());
}
```

And, mentioned the pattern inline as well.

```
constraints="{datePattern:'dd/MM/yyyy', strict:true}"
```